# Editable text to string

Tags: android

How can I convert editable text into string in Android ? Any solution?

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to do? Are you just trying to get the text out of a TextView or EditText?

Comment: i am  trying to display string in textView after converting editable text from editText

Comment: it is also possible to setText using an Editable...

Comment: Simply use `toString()` on the Editable instance to get String.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the String of an [Editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) object, right? If yes, try using `toString()`.

Comment: this is my sample code:
Editable newTxt=(Editable)userName1.getText();
String newString = newTxt.toString();
///////////////////////////////////////
but this is not working...

Comment: @bibek - __edit__ your question and put in details of the errors you are receiving.

Comment: dear sir, i want to display string in textview that comes from edittext.

Comment: finally i got it.i code is like..
EditText userName1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
String newString= (String)u serName1.getText().toString();

Comment: Do you understand where you went wrong? EditText is a view (a GUI element) whereas Editable is basically a String that can be changed.

Answer (score 28):

Based on this code (which you provided in response to Alex's answer):

```
Editable newTxt=(Editable)userName1.getText(); 
String newString = newTxt.toString();
```

It looks like you're trying to get the text out of a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) or [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html). If that's the case then this should work:

```
String newString = userName1.getText().toString();
```

Comment: how can i display same text in textView after getting from edittext?

Comment: TextView.setText.  You may find a better way to learn is to spend some time reading the docs and tutorials.

Comment: actually, i just want to display user name from textview thats come from editable text(input text).

Comment: Finally i solved the problem..
EditText userName1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
String newcommon = (String)userName1.getText().toString();

Answer (score 8):

This code work correctly only when u put into button click because at that time user put values into editable text and then when user clicks button it fetch the data and convert into string

```
EditText dob=(EditText)findviewbyid(R.id.edit_id);
String  str=dob.getText().toString();
```