# Convert Editable to String

Tags: android, string, type-conversion

I do not know why these solutions do not work.

I need convert from Editable to String

This solution not working:

```
Editable ploshad =editTextPloshad.getText();
String  ploshadNew=ploshad.toString();
```

and this

```
Editable ploshad =editTextPloshad.getText();
String  ploshadNew=(String)ploshad.toString();
```

ploshadNew is not a String

Comment: What is this then? Show us the package of Editable you're using.

Comment: what do you mean "not working" and "not a string"? toString is pretty much supposed to return a string, so what are you getting?

Answer (score 5):

If it's Android related, maybe you just need **EditText** and not **Editable** object?

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
String string = editText.getText().toString();
```

Source: [Editable text to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216201/editable-text-to-string)

Comment: i don't see how this is different from what is posted in the question

Comment: @njzk2 Look closer: EditText != Editable

Comment: yes, but no. you call getText().toString(), he calls getText(), and then toString(). it is only expanded, but it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The bugs that u telling are only undefined behavior.

For comparison never use == between editable and string, as they are bound get screwed up.

.equals() tests for value equality.