# Android How can I Convert a String to a Editable

Tags: java, android

We all know we can setText(String) to an editText box but if you want to get an editable variable from a string variable how do you do this?

For Temp I made an invisible editText box to set to then get from which turns the string into editable.

re: for my own reference String again = editablevariable.getText().toString()

Comment: Not sure what your trying to do. May be more information will help.

Comment: You want to make a copy of the string so you can modify it? If so, not necessary as you cannot modify String objects directly, it always result in a new String. If not, you need to add some more detail what you have and what you want (and what is not working)

Comment: see this post maybe help full http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216201/editable-text-to-string

Comment: Please post code to make your intentions clearer :)

Comment: I think I know what you are trying to ask: It can be described better in Kotlin though:<br><br>

say etUserName is an EditText,<br>
When you want to get a text from it:<br>
val strUserName = binding.etUserName.text.toString()<br>
then, when you have to set the text to it<br>
binding.etUserName.setText(signupFormParcel.strEmail)<br>
but you can't do the following directly:<br>
binding.etUserName.text = signupFormParcel.strEmail<br>
so you do:<br>
binding.etUserName.text = SpannableStringBuilder(signupFormParcel.strEmail)<br>
where strEmail is a string.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

As you probably found out, Editable is an interface so you cannot call `new Editable()`.
However an Editable is nothing more than a String with Spannables, so use [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html):

```
Editable editable = new SpannableStringBuilder("Pass a string here");
```

If you only want to change the Spannables, *never* the text itself, you can use a basic [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html).

Answer (score 15):

Use `Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(str)`
From the [android documentation:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.Factory.html#newEditable(java.lang.CharSequence))

> Returns a new SpannedStringBuilder from the specified CharSequence. You can override this to provide a different kind of Spanned.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22242893)

Comment: @Sree It does answer it, what I am saying is that he should use this function with the string to convert it to editable. So simply str is the string that he wants to convert to an editable.

Comment: @Sree From the android documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.Factory.html#newEditable(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: +1 : Cleaner than accepted answer, using a provided factory instead of relying on the type of underlying instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin, create a new extension method on String, like so:

```
fun String.toEditable() : Editable =
    Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(this)
```

Then you can assign to the EditText like so:

```
var edtFirstName : EditText = ...

edtFirstName = "Fred".toEditable()
```

Why this isn't a standard part of Android by now is beyond me.