# Android Regex - how to put hyphen after numbers?

Tags: java, android, regex

How can I put a hyphen after certain number of digits using `TextWatcher`?

I have some text where a user can input an 8 digit number (it could be anything). However, I want to display `00000000` as `0000-0000`, `12345678` as `1234-5678`, and so on.

Here is my current code:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

  if(editabletext.length() == 8) {
    editabletext.append("^(?=.*-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$");
  }

}
```

Comment: If the logic checks the length and it's exactly 8, why not just do this:
`editableText = editableText.substring(0,4) + "-" + editableText.substring(4);`?

Comment: I was thinking about that, I was more concentrating on it to have 8 digit. I am not sure.

Comment: editableText = editableTest.substring(0,4) + "-" + editableText.substring(4); ---- I didn't quiet understand how you do this ? and the reason for it .. Sorry I am new to Android please can you explain if you don't mind.

Comment: @JibinGeorge what it's doing is taking a substring from index 0 to index 4 (exlusive) of the original string, concatenating a "-", then concatenating a substring from index 4 to the end of the string. The result is a "-" stuck in the middle of an 8 character string. Since you specify an exact length of 8 in your `if`, the only way that code will run is if the user typed in 8 characters. So this will always put the character in the middle. How you handle what the user types in, is a different story. Check out jojodmo's answer below for a better picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to add a hyphen after 4 numbers, and then display the res normally, you could use this regex:

```
([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})
```

and replace it with:

```
$1-$2
```

The regex searches for 8 digits, putting the first 4 and the last 4 in capture groups. The first capture group is retrieved by using `$1`, and the second is retrieved by using `$2` in the replacement.

[Here's a live example](https://regex101.com/r/jB2jH9/1) on regex101.com

Instead of using a regex, you could instead just use [`.substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)), like so:

```
String firstFour = editabletext.substring(0, 4);
String lastFour = editabletext.substring(4);
String newEditableText = firstFour + "-" + lastFour
```

Which could be compressed to be:

```
editabletext = editabletext.substring(0, 4) + "-" + editabletext.substring(4);
```

So, here's what your code could look like:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

  if(editabletext.length() == 8){
    editabletext = editabletext.substring(0, 4) + "-" + editabletext.substring(4);

    //or you could use a regex:

    editabletext = editabletext.replaceAll("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})", "$1-$2")
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you, is this .substring part of the java method ? because I basically followed what you have put down but editabletext.substring(0, 4) + "-" + editabletext.substring(4); gives me error

Comment: [`.substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) is a Java method for Strings. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: editabletext is an EditText not a String , So this is what I have got ; String firstFour = editabletext.toString().substring(0, 4);
String lastFour = editabletext.toString().substring(4);
String newEditableText = firstFour + "-" + lastFour ----------------------------------

Comment: if(editabletext.length() == 8){
    editabletext = editabletext.substring(0, 4) + "-" + editabletext.substring(4);

    //or you could use a regex:

    editabletext = editabletext.replaceAll("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})", "$1-$2")
  }

Comment: This gives me an error saying that incompatible types ; required was android.widget.EditText and found ; java.String

Comment: so this is what I have got ; editabletext= editabletext.getText().toString().substring(0, 4) + "-" + editabletext.getText().toString().substring(4);

Comment: but however I am getting the same error saying that incompatible types ; required was android.widget.EditText and found ; java.lang.String

Comment: @JibinGeorge From what I understand from the [`documentation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html), you should be able to just do `Editable.toString()`. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2216219/2767207) out, too.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out the problem at all

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {     

    if (text.length() == 4) {
        text.append('-');
    }
}
```